# C++ Reading text from a file and parsing a string into an int array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing

First off I am not a C++ expert and am still learning so any insight would be greatly appreciated. This issue at first seemed a simple issue but after a few months, I am still unable to find a viable solution. I expect it has a simple answer that I am merely overlooking.

Below is some code that I wrote from reading similar threads here and on other sites. Basically I am trying to read from a text file that contains GF256 multiplication array(256 lines each 256 long). Reading line by line seems to be just fine evidenced by the line (cout << multi_ << endl;) where I see exactly what I need as a string for each line. It is at this point that I problems. I cannot seem to find a way to parse this string into an int array. I have many iterations of this code with different attempts at doing this, and yet none have worked for me. I assume there is a very simple solution for this. Again, any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
int kGF = 0;
int multiGFtemp[256 * 256];

int n;

int main()
{
    string multi_;

    ifstream fileGF("GF256MultiTable.txt");

    if(fileGF.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(fileGF,multi_))
        {


            cout << multi_ << endl;
            cin.get();
        }
        fileGF.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File is not open" << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    cout << multi_;

    stringstream stream2(multi_);

    while(stream2)
    {
        stream2 >> n;

        cout << n << endl;

        multiGFtemp[kGF] = n;
        kGF++;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < 256 * 256; k++)
    {
        /*
        cout << multiGFtemp[k] << " ";
        */
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the code you supplied the only line that has a chance at being processed is the last one, when you read text with `getline` is when you should process it. Consider writing a function that takes a line (string) and an array as an argument and fills the latter with the contents of the first, the question of reading numbers from a text line can be answered by googling "CSV C++" and seeing how others have done it.

Comment: Can you show an example for how the file is formatted?

Comment: It is a .txt file formatted as such where ; is a new line. 0    0    0    0...;1    1   1    1    1...; 1    2    3   5...; etc. There is an undefined amount of white space between each number but there is a definite new line at the end of each 256 numbered row.

Answer (score 0):

Your program parses the contents of `multi_`, which at that point is the last line of the file.
You could move that into the loop, but that would only complicate things – if you just want the 256 * 256 numbers in a plain array, you can ignore the file structure.

This is one way of slurping that file into an array:

```
int multiGFtemp[256 * 256];

int main()
{
    ifstream fileGF("GF256MultiTable.txt");
    int kGF = 0;
    while (kGF < 256 * 256 && fileGF >> multiGFtemp[kGF])
    {
        kGF++;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < kGF; k++)
    {
        cout << multiGFtemp[k] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Perfectly simple. I tried moving the parse into the loop and was able to get it to work that way as well, but the solution you provide here is much simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to read a string in a known format into arguments.
For example you have file that contains a line: "X = 1035, Y = 6658".
If this is the case, i prefer to use sscanf.

for example:

```
string format("X = %d, Y = %d");
string str("X = 1035, Y = 6658");
int x, y;
sscanf(str.c_str(), format, &x, &y);
```

Comment: You are missing the answer for the main question which is about parsing the line into an array.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost library might help you here.
Have a look at [Boost String Algo Split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp) for example.